# Compute the Eulerian number

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, combinatorics, permutations

The [Eulerian number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) `A(n, m)` is the number of permutations of `[1, 2, ..., n]` in which exactly `m` elements are greater than the previous element. These are also called *rises*. For example, if `n = 3`, there are 3! = 6 permutations of `[1, 2, 3]`

```
1 2 3
 < <  2 elements are greater than the previous

1 3 2
 < >  1 ...

2 1 3
 > <  1 ...

2 3 1
 < >  1 ...

3 1 2
 > <  1 ...

3 2 1
 > >  0 ...
```

So the outputs for `A(3, m)` for `m` in `[0, 1, 2, 3]` will be

```
A(3, 0) = 1
A(3, 1) = 4
A(3, 2) = 1
A(3, 3) = 0
```

Also, this is the OEIS sequence [A173018](https://oeis.org/A173018).

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
- The input `n` will be a nonnegative integer and `m` will be a integer in the range `[0, 1, ..., n]`.

### Test Cases

```
n   m   A(n, m)
0   0   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
2   0   1
2   1   1
2   2   0
3   0   1
3   1   4
3   2   1
3   3   0
4   0   1
4   1   11
4   2   11
4   3   1
4   4   0
5   1   26
7   4   1191
9   5   88234
10  5   1310354
10  7   47840
10  10  0
12  2   478271
15  6   311387598411
17  1   131054
20  16  1026509354985
42  42  0
```

Comment: Any limits on `n, m`?

Comment: There is no limit, but it's not required that your submission be able to completely execute a test case in a certain amount of time, only have the correct logic. Preferably, I'd like submissions to handle values up to 20, but I left it without a performance requirement to allow brute-force solutions that may only work up to `n = 10`.

Comment: Can the input have m >= n, n > 0?

Comment: Shouldn't, "m will be a integer in the range [0, 1, ..., n]" be "...[0, 1, ..., n-1]"?

Comment: @feersum Your solution can support any `m` if desired, but I only require that it be valid for 0 <= *m* <= *n* with 0 <= *n*.

Comment: I ask because you don't have any such example in your test cases (where m = n and the answer is 0).

Comment: @JonathanAllan That was my original definition but I changed it in meta to fit the OEIS sequence, but this was probably hard to observe since I didn't update the test cases to include `m = n`.

Comment: @feersum Thanks, it slipped my mind to add those test cases after I changed the definition in meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ!Z>2\Sċ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZIhWj4yXFPEiw&input=&args=OQ+NQ) (takes a while) or [verify the smaller test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZIhWj4yXFPEiwrFvDsiw6ciRw&input=&args=MCwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMiwgMiwgMywgMywgMywgMywgNCwgNCwgNCwgNCwgNCwgNSwgNw+MCwgMCwgMSwgMCwgMSwgMiwgMCwgMSwgMiwgMywgMCwgMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgMSwgNA).

#### How it works

```
Œ!Z>2\Sċ  Main link. Arguments: n, m

Œ!        Generate the matrix of all permutations of [1, ..., n].
  Z       Zip/transpose, placing the permutations in the columns.
   >2\    Compare columns pairwise with vectorizing greater-than.
          This generates a 1 in the column for each rise in that permutation.
      S   Compute the vectorizing sum of the columns, counting the number of rises.
       ċ  Count how many times m appears in the computed counts.
```

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>50</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
f=(n,m,d=n-m)=>m?d&&f(--n,m)*++m+f(n,m-2)*d:1
```

Based on the recursive formula:

```
A(n, m) = (n - m)A(n - 1, m - 1) + (m + 1)A(n - 1, m)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,m,d=n-m)=>m?d&&f(--n,m)*++m+f(n,m-2)*d:1

console.log(f( 0,  0));  // 1
console.log(f( 1,  0));  // 1
console.log(f( 1,  1));  // 0
console.log(f( 2,  0));  // 1
console.log(f( 2,  1));  // 1
console.log(f( 2,  2));  // 0
console.log(f( 3,  0));  // 1
console.log(f( 3,  1));  // 4
console.log(f( 3,  2));  // 1
console.log(f( 3,  3));  // 0
console.log(f( 4,  0));  // 1
console.log(f( 4,  1));  // 11
console.log(f( 4,  2));  // 11
console.log(f( 4,  3));  // 1
console.log(f( 4,  4));  // 0
console.log(f( 5,  1));  // 26
console.log(f( 7,  4));  // 1191
console.log(f( 9,  5));  // 88234
console.log(f(10,  5));  // 1310354
console.log(f(10,  7));  // 47840
console.log(f(10, 10));  // 0
console.log(f(12,  2));  // 478271
console.log(f(15,  6));  // 311387598411
console.log(f(17,  1));  // 131054
console.log(f(20, 16));  // 1026509354985
console.log(f(42, 42));  // 0
```

Answer (score 4):

### CJam (<strike>21</strike> 19 bytes - or 18 if argument order is free)

```
{\e!f{2ew::>1b=}1b}
```

This is an anonymous block (function) which takes `n m` on the stack. (If it's permitted to take `m n` on the stack then the `\` can be saved). It computes all  permutations and filters, so the [online test suite](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX5dMy97fkBACgp7XGUhZnsyZXc6Oj4xYj19MWJ9Cgp-PX0v&input=MCAgIDAgICAxCjEgICAwICAgMQoxICAgMSAgIDAKMiAgIDAgICAxCjIgICAxICAgMQoyICAgMiAgIDAKMyAgIDAgICAxCjMgICAxICAgNAozICAgMiAgIDEKMyAgIDMgICAwCjQgICAwICAgMQo0ICAgMSAgIDExCjQgICAyICAgMTEKNCAgIDMgICAxCjQgICA0ICAgMAo1ICAgMSAgIDI2CjcgICA0ICAgMTE5MQ) must be rather limited.

Thanks to Martin for pointing out an approximation to `filter-with-parameter`.

#### Dissection

```
{        e# Define a block. Stack: n m
  \      e#   Flip the stack to give m n
  e!f{   e#   Generate permutations of [0 .. n-1] and map with parameter m
    2ew  e#     Stack: m perm; generate the list of n-1 pairs of consecutive
         e#     elements of perm
    ::>  e#     Map each pair to 1 if it's a rise and 0 if it's a fall
    1b   e#     Count the falls
    =    e#     Map to 1 if there are m falls and 0 otherwise
  }
  1b     e#   Count the permutations with m falls
}
```

Note that the Eulerian numbers are symmetric: `E(n, m) = E(n, n-m)`, so it's irrelevant whether you count falls or rises.

#### Efficiently: 32 bytes

```
{1a@{0\+_ee::*(;\W%ee::*W%.+}*=}
```

[Online test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%5D3%2F%7B~%40%40%0A%0A%7B1a%40%7B0%5C%2B_ee%3A%3A*(%3B%5CW%25ee%3A%3A*W%25.%2B%7D*%3D%7D%0A%0A~%3D%7D%2F&input=0%20%20%200%20%20%201%0A1%20%20%200%20%20%201%0A1%20%20%201%20%20%200%0A2%20%20%200%20%20%201%0A2%20%20%201%20%20%201%0A2%20%20%202%20%20%200%0A3%20%20%200%20%20%201%0A3%20%20%201%20%20%204%0A3%20%20%202%20%20%201%0A3%20%20%203%20%20%200%0A4%20%20%200%20%20%201%0A4%20%20%201%20%20%2011%0A4%20%20%202%20%20%2011%0A4%20%20%203%20%20%201%0A4%20%20%204%20%20%200%0A5%20%20%201%20%20%2026%0A7%20%20%204%20%20%201191%0A9%20%20%205%20%20%2088234%0A10%20%205%20%20%201310354%0A10%20%207%20%20%2047840%0A10%20%2010%20%200%0A12%20%202%20%20%20478271%0A15%20%206%20%20%20311387598411%0A17%20%201%20%20%20131054%0A20%20%2016%20%201026509354985%0A42%20%2042%20%200).

This implements the recurrence on whole rows.

```
{          e# Define a block. Stack: n m
  1a@      e#   Push the row for n=0: [1]; and rotate n to top of stack
  {        e#   Repeat n times:
           e#     Stack: m previous-row
    0\+_   e#     Prepend a 0 to the row and duplicate
    ee::*  e#     Multiply each element by its index
           e#     This gives A[j] = j * E(i-1, j-1)
    (;     e#     Pop the first element, so that A[j] = (j+1) * E(i-1, j)
    \W%    e#     Get the other copy of the previous row and reverse it
    ee::*  e#     Multiply each element by its index
           e#     This gives B[j] = j * E(i-1, i-1-j)
    W%     e#     Reverse again, giving B[j] = (i-j) * E(i-1, j-1)
    .+     e#     Pointwise addition
  }*
  =        e#   Extract the element at index j
}
```

Comment: It's shorter to avoid the variable by using a map: `{e!f{2ew::>1b=}1e=}`. Or just for fun: `{e!f{2ew::>+:-}0e=}`

Comment: That was stupid, of course. The `1e=` in the first solution can be `1b`.

Comment: You are allowed to use your own argument order

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
:Y@!d0>s=s
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OllAIWQwPnM9cw&input=Nwo0)

#### Explanation

Consider as an example inputs [`n=3`, `m=1`](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiVZQCFkMD5zPXM&input=Mwox). You can place a `%` symbol to comment out the code from that point onwards and thus see the intermediate results. For example, the link shows the stack after the first step.

```
:      % Input n implicitly. Push [1 2 ... n]
       % STACK: [1 2 ... n]
Y@     % Matrix of all permutations, one on each row
       % STACK: [1 2 3; 1 3 2; 2 1 3; 2 3 1; 3 1 2; 3 2 1]
!      % Transpose
       % STACK: [1 1 2 2 3 3; 2 3 1 3 1 2; 3 2 3 1 2 1]
d      % Consecutive differences along each column
       % STACK: [1 2 -1 1 -2 -1; 1 -1 2 -2 1 -1]
0>     % True for positive entries
       % STACK: [1 1 0 1 0 0; 1 0 1 0 1 0]
s      % Sum of each column
       % STACK: [2 1 1 1 1 0]
=      % Input m implicitly. Test each entry for equality with m
       % STACK: [0 1 1 1 1 0]
s      % Sum. Implicitly display
       % STACK: 4
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>55</s> 56 bytes

```python
a=lambda n,m:n>=m>0and(n-m)*a(n-1,m-1)-~m*a(n-1,m)or m<1
```

All tests at **[repl.it](https://repl.it/EAcw/3)**

Applies the recursive formula on OEIS.
Note that `+(m+1)*a(n-1,m)` is golfed to `-~m*a(n-1,m)`.
(May return boolean values to represent `1` or `0`. Returns `True` when `n<0 and m<=0` or `m<0`.)

Comment: There are various other ways to handle the edge cases. It suffices to handle `m<1 ? 1 : m==n ? 0 : formula`, equivalently `m%n<1 ? (m<1) : formula`; or alternatively `m<1 ? (n>=0) : formula`.

Comment: I got it, just updating thanks

Comment: Since our answers are very similar, and yours was posted first (and is shorter), I'll go ahead and delete mine.

Comment: @Loovjo A little bit of frantic tweaking though :( You got an ^vote from me anyway!

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```
_~f~0=1
n_~f~m_:=If[m>n,0,(n-m)f[n-1,m-1]+(m+1)f[n-1,m]]
```

And here is a 59 byte version implementing the definition more literally:

```
Count[Count@1/@Sign/@Differences/@Permutations@Range@#,#2]&
```

Comment: Why not just `f[n_,m_]:=...` for 49?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'm not sure I understand. How does that handle the base case?

Comment: OK, something was cached - just did it in a new worksheet and it failed with recursion limit. :)

Comment: There is also the formula which uses 46 bytes `Sum[Binomial[#+1,k](#2+1-k)^#(-1)^k,{k,0,#2}]&` which might be possible to golf more

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 53 bytes

```python
t=lambda n,k:n and(n-k)*t(n-1,k-1)-~k*t(n-1,k)or k==0
```

Recursion from OEIS. Outputs Boolean `True` as `1` when `n==k`.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB / Octave, 40 bytes

```
@(n,m)sum(sum(diff((perms(1:n))')>0)==m)
```

This is a port of my MATL answer, in the form of an anonymous function. Call it as `ans(7,4)`.

[Try it at Ideone](http://ideone.com/VXYZY4).

Answer (score 2):

## GameMaker Language, 62 bytes

This is a recursive script `A` based on @Arnauld's formula.

```
n=argument0;m=argument1;return (n-m)*A(n-1,m-1)+(m+1)*A(n-1,m)
```

Comment: Haven't seen THAT in a while!

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 98 bytes

```
sub a{my($b,$c)=@_;return$c?$c>$b?0:($b-$c)*a($b-1,$c-1)+($c+1)*a($b-1,$c):1;}print a(@ARGV[0,1]);
```

Based on the same property as Arnauld's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 72 bytes

Recursive function following the logic on OEIS.

```
A=function(n,m)if(!m)1 else if(m-n)0 else(n-m)*A(n-1,m-1)+(m+1)*A(n-1,m)
```

This challenge turned out to be quite close between the different approaches I tried. For instance, using the wikipedia formula and looping over the sum resulted in 92 bytes:

```
function(n,m){s=0;if(!n)1 else for(k in -1:m+1)s=c(s,(-1)^k*choose(n+1,k)*(m+1-k)^n);sum(s)}
```

or the vectorized version for 87 bytes:

```
function(n,m)if(!m)1 else sum(sapply(-1:m+1,function(k)(-1)^k*choose(n+1,k)*(m+1-k)^n))
```

and finally the brute force solution (103 bytes) that generates a matrix of all permutations by using the `permute` package and the function `allPerms`. This approach only works up to `n<8` though.

```
function(n,m){if(!m)1 else sum(apply(rbind(1:n,permute:::allPerms(n)),1,function(x)sum(diff(x)>0))==m)}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 141 bytes

```
(count(λ(x)(= x m))(for/list((t(permutations(range 1(+ 1 n)))))(count
(λ(x)x)(for/list((i(sub1 n)))(>(list-ref t(+ 1 i))(list-ref t i))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f n m)
  (let* ((l (range 1 (add1 n)))                ; create a list till n
         (pl (permutations l))                 ; get all permutations
         (enl (for/list ((t pl))               ; check each permutation; 
                (define rl
                  (for/list ((i (sub1 n)))     ; check if an element is a 'rise'
                    (> (list-ref t (add1 i))
                       (list-ref t i))))
                (count (lambda(x)x) rl))))     ; how many numbers are 'rises'
    (count (lambda(x) (= x m)) enl)))          ; how many permutations had m rises
                                               ; i.e. Eulerian number
```

Testing:

```
(f 3 0)
(f 3 1)
(f 3 2)
(f 3 3)
(f 4 2)
(f 5 1)
(f 7 4)
```

Output:

```
1
4
1
0
11
26
1191
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

This answer uses an algorithm similar to the one Dennis uses in his [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96751/47581). The original definition counts `<` while I count `>`. This ends up being equivalent in the end. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O1LilahgO1xaZFgiaT4iwqNNzqNgTWM&input=Mgo0)

```
;R╨`;\ZdX"i>"£MΣ`Mc
```

**Ungolfing**

```
         Implicit input m, then n.
;        Duplicate n. Stack: n, n, m
R        Push range [1..n].
╨        Push all n-length permutations of the range.
`...`M   Map the following function over each permutation p.
  ;\       Duplicate and rotate p so that we have a list of the next elements of p.
  Z        Zip rot_p and p.
           (order of operands here means the next element is first,
            so we need to use > later)
  dX       Remove the last pair as we don't compare the last and first elements of the list.
  "i>"£    Create a function that will flatten a list and check for a rise.
  M        Map that function over all the pairs.
  Σ        Count how many rises there are in each permutation.
c        Using the result of the map and the remaining m, 
          count how many permutations have m rises.
         Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift), 82 <del>88</del> Bytes

[`func A(_ n:Int,_ m:Int)->Int{return m<1 ?1:n>m ?(n-m)*A(n-1,m-1)+(m+1)*A(n-1,m):0}`](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5815bbb41503df5a9307a0b7)

Just the same recursive formula in a language that is definitely not for golf

Answer (score 0):

## J, 28 bytes

```
+/@((!>:)~*(^~#\.)*_1^])i.,]
```

Uses the formula

[image: formula]

### Usage

```
   f =: +/@((!>:)~*(^~#\.)*_1^])i.,]
   0 f 0
1
   1 f 0
1
   1 f 1
0
   (f"+i.,]) 6
1 57 302 302 57 1 0
   20x f 16x
1026509354985
```

### Explanation

```
+/@((!>:)~*(^~#\.)*_1^])i.,]  Input: n (LHS), m (RHS)
                        i.    Range [0, 1, ..., m-1]
                           ]  Get m
                          ,   Join to get k = [0, 1, ..., m]
                      ]       Get k
                   _1^        Raise -1 to each in k
              #\.               Get the length of each suffix of k
                                Forms the range [m+1, m, ..., 2, 1]
            ^~                  Raise each value by n
                  *           Multiply elementwise with (-1)^k
    (   )~                      Commute operators
      >:                        Increment n
     !                          Binomial coefficient, C(n+1, k)
          *                   Multiply elementwise
+/@                           Reduce by addition to get the sum and return
```